# React-Native One time binding

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to assign a value from an object in the state without binding it to the state.

```
<TextInput value={this.state.bigObject.sub.name}/>
<TextInput value={this.state.bigObject.sub.name.toString()}/> // also tried this
```

When the textbox is edited, the value is being reverted to the value in the state. I do not wish to update the state `onChange`, rather I want to update the state `onSubmitEditing` only. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

use setNativeProps to directly manipulate the TextInput. hope that helps

```
 <TextInput
          ref={component => this._textInput = component}
          style={{height: 50, width: 200, marginHorizontal: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ccc'}}
        />
this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
```